# Is there a way to enable Firefox to remember my credit card details?

Tags: windows, firefox

I recently switched from Chrome to Firefox and the only thing I really miss is how Chrome fills in credit card information on payment pages.

1. Does Firefox have this feature?
2. How do I enable this feature if #1 is true?

Comment: I find it hilarious that your user name is "AngryHacker" and you are asking how to store credit card information in a web browser. ROFLOL

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not do so by default. However there might be addon's that can do the job. Search for Autofill addons.

It is highly not recommended, especially if you're sharing your computer with someone else and some websites can steal your card details using hidden forms.

http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2017/01/10/autofill-flaw-scam-websites-steal-internet-users-credit-card/